# Mock new Object using Mockito only

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method code like this in a class

```
public List<Auth_token> getAuthToken(String User) throws SQLException {
        List<Auth_token> usersList = new ArrayList<Auth_token>();
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        try {

            OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setURL("blah blah");
            dataSource.setUser("blah");

            //LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"username +: "+config.getUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword("blah");

            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            String query = "blah query";
//more code
}
```

I need to mock oracle datasource using mockito only. I know how to do using power mockito but i have to do this using mockito only. Please help me.

Comment: You'll need to change your implementation so that the OracleDataSource instance, or a factory for creating it, is injected.

Comment: I can't change the implementation as that code was written by someone else. I Only need to improve the code coverage.

Comment: With mockito, you don't change the written code. Rather, you mock what the code would respond with (without going to the database). For example, in the code you omitted, are you returning a select statement? Perhaps you could mock the select statement with a series of lines and avoid the database call.

Comment: You cannot mock this, this is a design implementation flaw, you are trying to get the connection every time a method is called the implementation itself is wrong and finding hard to write unit test prooves that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock something that is created with a `new` operator with `mockito`.

You have to decouple your data source creation code from the query execution.

You can introduce [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to achieve that for instance.